# How to make full wave rectifier?

Tags: cmos

I observed one paper [A highly efficient interface circuit for ultra-low-voltage energy harvesting] and i tried Full-wave rectifier [attached in below].

[image]

But this circuit generating output wave form same as half-wave rectifier [observe in below].

I want to know this waveform is wrong or not?. Please, kindly consider my request and give me help.

[image]

Check 1

[image]

Check 2
[image]

Comment: Try moving the ground node to vout- and see what happens to your vout+ trace.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong ground reference for your output voltage. You are measuring between GND and V+ instead of between V- and V+. When you do this you only get a half-wave output rather than a full wave.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRu8y3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How to check the two halves?? I add last picture.

Comment: I expanded and clarified the answer, see if that helps.

Comment: I add last picture. One more Question. I want sine wave input(Check1) but simulation's input voltage is only positive voltage. Why change the postive signal.?? –

Comment: The sources and drains in your circuit are mixed up.